# Retrieving credentials from DB to use in .env file

Tags: laravel-5

I have some credentials(twilio) which were placed in my .env file. However, now I am currently storing these credentials for each user in my database instead.  I am trying to retrieve the information so that the application may use it just as if it were still in my .env file, but the application is not finding the credentials.

I tried calling it from the AppServiceProvider's boot method by using [laravel's env()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration) to see if it would work but it didn't.

I heard about something called *memoization* but didn't really understand how to implement it.

---

**services.php**

```
...
'twilio' => [
    'account_sid' => env('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'),
    'auth_token' => env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'),
    'from' => env('TWILIO_FROM'),
],
...
```

What are the best approaches which could be taken with this problem? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if your doing on a per user basic your most likely best providing a different means than the built in config

There are a few packages for such things e.g. https://packagist.org/packages/bluemanos/database-config

https://packagist.org/packages/jameswmcnab/config-db

You may want to assess those, otherwise create a model backed onto your db and wherever you call config change calls to a method for retrieving item from the database